# Is there a way to remove all sessionStorage items with keys that match a certain pattern?

Tags: javascript, browser, sessionstorage

Lets say my `sessionStorage` contains three objects who's keys are `foo`, `foobar`, and `baz`. Is there a way that I can call `.removeItem` or somehow delete all items in `sessionStorage` who's keys match `foo`? In this example I'd be left with only the item who's key is `baz`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Update September 20, 2014** As pointed out by Jordan Trudgett the reverse loop is more appropriate

You can only achieve it programmatically as `sessionStorage` exposes a limited set of methods: `getItem(key)`, `setItem(key, value)`, `removeItem(key)`, `key(position)`, `clear()` and `length()`:

```
var n = sessionStorage.length;
while(n--) {
  var key = sessionStorage.key(n);
  if(/foo/.test(key)) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
  }  
}
```

See Nicholas C. Zakas' blog entry for more details:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/

Comment: You should iterate over the storage object in reverse order, because when you remove the item, the indexes get changed. Doing it this way may miss some items.

Comment: It should be mentioned that unlike other arrays, sessionStorage keys are indexed from 1 to sessionStorage.length. If you were to use a for loop, the indices should be correct.

Comment: If you have pattern in variable as a string - var patternStr = 'foo'; you can use (new RegExp(patternStr)).test(key)

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like

```
Object.keys(sessionStorage)
  .filter(function(k) { return /foo/.test(k); })
  .forEach(function(k) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(k);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both local and sessionStorage are objects you can go through their properties like this:

```js
    for (var obj in localStorage) {
      if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(obj) && obj == "myKey") {
        localStorage.removeItem(obj);
      }
    }
```

and remove the desired values by key, here it's "myKey" for example.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all session storage items:

```
sessionStorage.clear()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 angular.forEach(sessionStorage, function (item,key) {
          sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
      });
```

This will delete everything from sessionStorage

Comment: There is no Angular tag, so your answer isn't useful in this context.